# ASP.NET Core MVC - ajax, jQuery, json, javascript - retriving data from json, api controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, polish

I want to lazy load using button the rest of articles form chosen category. Every time I submit "Show more" button I get two requests: the proper one with data in json and "undefined" request and I can't retrieve data from my json. Below is my code where I get the JSON data. Maybe should I add a jquery library? The "undefined" request is affected by this error I guess: jsfiddle.net/dhsom5n3. From 3035 line to the end the lines are underlined on red.

[image: undefined request body]
[image: the proper one request body]

```
    <button id="articles-button" onclick="ShowMore(2)">Pokaż więcej</button>

@section Scripts {
<script>
        
        
 
        let ShowMore = function(quantity) {
            let filterCategory = '@ViewData["kat"]';
            var path = '/api/lazyloading' + '?id=' + @Model.Last().ArticleId + '&quantity=' + quantity + '&filterName=' + filterCategory;
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onload = function() {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    try {
                        const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        for(var index in data) {
                    let article = data[index];
 
                    let newRow = document.createElement("tr");
                    
                    let name = document.createElement("td");
                    $(name).text(article["ArticleName"]);
                    
                    let price = document.createElement("td");
                    $(price).text("$" + article["ArticlePrice"])
 
                    let imageData = document.createElement("td");
                    let image = document.createElement("img");
 
                    $(imageData).append(image);
 
                    $(image).addClass("miniature");
                    $(image).attr("src", "/" + article["Image"]);
 
                    let formData = document.createElement("td");
 
                    let form = document.createElement("form");
                    $(form).attr("action", "https://localhost:44388/Shop/Display");
                    $(form).attr("method", "post");
                    $(form).addClass("add-to-cart");
 
                    let id = document.createElement("input");
                    $(id).prop("type", "hidden");
                    $(id).prop("name", "id")
                    $(id).val(article["ArticleId"]);
 
                    let button = document.createElement("input");
                    $(button).prop("type", "submit");
                    $(button).addClass("btn btn-primary");
                    $(button).val("Dodaj do koszyka");
                    $(form).append(button);
 
                    $(formData).append(form);
                    $(form).append(id);
 
                    $(newRow).append(name);
                    $(newRow).append(price);
                    $(newRow).append(imageData);
                    $(newRow).append(formData);
 
 
                    $("#body").append(newRow);
                }
 
 
 
                if (data.length === 0) {
                    $("#articles-button").hide();
                } else {
                    last = data[data.length - 1]["id"];
                }
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.warn('error with json');
                    }
                } else if (this.status === 204) {
                    window.alert("No elements");
                } else {
                    console.warn('Received' + this.status);
                }
            };
            xhr.open("get", path)
            xhr.send();
        }
    </script>
    }
```

Comment: Why use multiple accounts to write the same question?

Comment: Also I believe that in your script you need to use `'@Model.Last().ArticleId'` not `@Model.Last().ArticleId`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it didn't help

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen FYI you only need `'` if it's a string (or similar, eg guid).  In this case it's (probably) an integer so doesn't need the quotes.  It should render as eg `'?id=' + 3 + '&quantity` - so should really be `'?id=@Model.Last().ArticleId&quantity=`

Comment: I know you've having issues with your `var last=` variable, but putting it on the url like that `var path = '/api/lazyloading' + '?id=' + @Model.Last().ArticleId +` means it will be hardcoded when the page is rendered and you'll only ever get the 2nd page (unless you rewrite your js each time, which you shouldn't)

Comment: Your button is POSTing your form, so you get a "second" request.  Change it to `<button id="articles-button" type='button'`

Comment: @freedomn-m but what about quantity parameter? Where do you pass it?

Comment: ??  You have working code (to a point), but then after it works, your button submits your form.  Make it so that the button doesn't submit; that's your issue.   "What about xx" - what about it?